# Error when using custom format file, "LaTeX Error: No \title given."

Tags: errors, format-files, mylatexformat

For faster compilation, I'm attempting to use a custom format file. However, it seems to misbehave when I try to use `\maketitle` … even though I use `\title{Test}`.

#### MWE

I've created a `preamble.tex` with the following content:

```tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\endofdump
```

I've then compiled it to a `.fmt` file with `pdflatex -output-directory /tmp/ -ini -jobname=preamble "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx /tmp/preamble.tex`, and it produces `preamble.fmt` with no warnings or errors.

Then I create a `demo.tex` with the following content

```tex
%& /tmp/preamble

\author{tec}
\date{2023-02-02}
\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Hello

\end{document}
```

When I attempt to compile this with `latexmk -f -pdf -pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=/tmp /tmp/demo.tex` it fails, with the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: No \title given.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 
     
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg)

LaTeX Warning: No \author given.
```

If I remove the `\maketitle`, it works as expected and I get a PDF containing "Hello".

I also tried setting the title and author with

```tex
\makeatletter
\gdef\@title{Test}
\gdef\@author{tec}
\makeatother
```

however, I still ran into the error above.

---

If anybody could help me work out what is going on, and how I might fix this, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: This maybe isn't the issue but could you put `\usepackage{hyperref}` as the last package in `preamble.tex` and try again? It is uncanny how many issues arise when `hyperref` isn't the last package loaded so it would at least eliminate that as a cause

Comment: I can confirm that putting `hyperref` last makes no difference. In fact, I've been able to make a much more minimal MWE.

Comment: `mylatexformat` starts reading files from `\begin{document}`. so you have to move `\title{…}`, `\author{…}` etc. *after* `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I have missed a rather crucial part of the `mylatexformat` docs. The `\endofdump` command should be in both `preamble.tex` *and* `demo.tex`.

If I add `\endofdump` to the start of `demo.tex`, everything works as expected.

Comment: Somehow more precisely: `mylatexformat` has been made to dump the whole preamble of a document. So you just don't need two files. But if you use two file, everything before `\begin{document}` (or `\endofdump`) of the *document* file is ignored. So you cannot set `\author`, `\title` and `\date` before `\begin{document}` but only after it (or use an addition `\endofdump`).

Comment: I'm aware I don't need two files, the idea here is that the same precompiled format file can be used with many `.tex` files :)